# smbclient deltree with read-only directories

Tags: samba, smb, smbclient

I'm trying to delete files on a NetApp server using `smbclient //servername/share -c "deltree directory_to_delete"`. It works except for folders which have the read-only flag set. In this case, the command aborts with `NT_STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE`.

I can view the flags with `smbclient //servername/share -c "ls directory_to_delete/*"` and remove them with `smbclient //servername/share -c "setmode directory_to_delete/subdir_with_ro_flag -r"`, but only per directory.

Is there a way to automate this (remove the read-only flag recursively) or any other way how to recursively delete a directory with read-only subdirectories?

Btw. the Windows explorer does not complain when deleting such directories (using the same credentials). I'm sure it removes the ro-flag silently.

Comment: "_Is there a way to automate this […]?_" - is mounting the filesystem "properly" (i.e. with `mount -t cifs //servername/share …`) an option so that you can use `rm -rf`, rather than using `smbclient`?

Comment: Yes, this would be my fallback solution. The thing is that my `smbclient` command is part of a script which I don't want to rewrite if there is an other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for NetApp is to enable the option `cifs.perm_check_ro_del_ok`.

```
options cifs.perm_check_ro_del_ok on
```

Source: https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196993/html/GUID-627F5269-6DE9-4FC8-BBC1-B1F34101FDFA.html

Btw. the read-only flag on directories has a complete other meaning than one would expect, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1720951/folder-icon-desktop-ini-and-file-attributes/1720961#1720961).